# Save a local attachment on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

Though paperclip gem is generally used for easy file uploads, I have a similar requirement at server side. I have generated an image at server and want to save it in various styles as configured in paperclip options.

I have generated the migration and my model looks like this:

```
attr_accessible :genimg
has_attached_file :genimg
  styles: { mini: '48x48>', small: '100x100>',
            product: '240x240>', large: '600x600>' },
  default_style: :product
  url: '/images/:basename.:extension',
  path: ':rails_root/app/assets/images/:basename.:extension'
  convert_options: { all: '-strip -auto-orient' }
```

Is there a way I can save my local image in various formats using paperclip. How can I do so? If that's not possible, what are the other possible way to try out?

Comment: what exactly is not working for you? as you have specified styles in your model it should work, the only thing I aware of is how you used styles declarations, compared to paperclip docs.

Comment: I am not attaching the images from the client. Rather I simply want to pass on a local file at the server to paperclip so that it can process  and save it in different formats as per the configuration. Thats the part I am stuck as I am not aware how an image be passed to paperclip on the server side. I tried overwriting the filename manually but that didnt help.

Comment: so you don't want to upload an image, instead you want to give paperclip a location of the file and generate styles for that image?

Comment: join this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34586/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-17983635-save-a-local-attachment-on-the-server

Comment: Yeah, I am new to stackoverflow and have just started. Are you looking for any specific configuration/information? If it helps, I can pretty much appear on other chat clients.

Comment: can you type in the chat that I created for us?

Comment: No, I am not able to type in over there. I am trying out the answer that you suggested. Will come back shortly after trying it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class YourController < ActionController::Base
  def your_action
    @image = Image.find 1 # (might be other way how you get the asset)

    file_path = '/path/to/your/file'
    file      = File.open(file_path, 'r')

    @image.asset = file
    @image.save
  end
end
```

in console you might do:

```
Image.new(:data => File.new(path_to_your_file, "r"))
```

Comment: Thanks @rmagnum2002 for suggesting the answer. I used RMagick to read the asset: Adopted your suggestion in the code like: `@image = Magick::Image.read("app/assets/images/processed/#{@cardfrontimgfilename}").first
file_path = 'app/assets/images/processed/'
file      = File.open(file_path, 'r')
@image.asset = file
@image.save`. However, encountered the following error: `NoMethodError (undefined method `asset=' for #<Magick::Image:0x007f9bca6bc840>):`. Seems I am missing something basic over here. Am I doing something wrong? Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: can't say for sure, can you post your model that is related to assets? I mean the one who is charge of storing the image in db.

Comment: and why `File.open(file_path, 'r')` isn't working for you? do you have any errors using it?

Comment: File.open is working fine. There are no issues over there. Its just that its not able to use the asset on the @image object.@image successfully reads the image but using the asset fails. Model defined is: `class ImgStore < ActiveRecord::Base
<content as mentioned in the question>
end`. Just to try it out if I comment the asset line, I get the following error: `Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for app/assets/images/processed/ofi2013-08-01 13:02:48 +0530.png PNG 600x600 600x600+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 194kb):`